# texify: how to invoke bibtex8 instead of bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, compiling, miktex, texify

Suppose that I need to run

```
bibtex8.exe -B -c cp1251.csf
```

or something like that in order to produce correct bibliography list; cp1251.csf comes with the gost package but it makes no difference in the context of my question since I am getting correct output when I am running bibtex8 from the command prompt of from WinEdt menu. I want for texify to run bibtex8 instead of default bibtex as well.  It is possible to instruct texify (from the miktex bundle) to run bibtex8 instead of bibtex by setting the BIBTEX environment variable as follows

```
SET BIBTEX=bibtex8
```

But texify fails if I am trying to pass options to the bibtex8 execuatable. In particular, with

```
SET BIBTEX=bibtex8 -B -c cp1251.csf
```

texify aborts with the message

```
texify: "bibtex8 -B -c cp1251.csf" could not be found.
```

Is there a way to pass options to bibtex8 over texify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try to write a batch-file which calls bibtex with the correct options and set the variable BIBTEX so that it points to this batch file.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. WinEdt actually runs such batch file (texify.edt). It first calls bibtex.edt macro (which I've modified accordingly to my needs) and then invokes texify.exe which calls bibtex.exe by default.

Comment: I don't understand. If you can do `SET BIBTEX=bibtex8` to change to bibtex8, why can't you do `SET BIBTEX=bibtexBlubb` where bibtexBlubb is a batch file which calls bibtex8 with the options you want?

Comment: Fisher: indeed that works if the batch file is placed to bib directory of miktex and registered in the miktex database. However this is a palliative solution;  it has apperent drawback. Several users put similar feature request to miktex developers. Hopefully, it will appear soon.

Answer (score 2):

I have also tried to pass options (in my case `--wolfgang`) to bibtex8 under texify. If this were possible, presumably it would be possible to pass options to makeindex/xindy in the same way. However, texify features the option `--mkidx-option` to [pass options to the index generator](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/texify.html). There is no corresponding option for bibtex. Therefore, I suspect that your request is not possible.